# Cannot find serial device

Tags: mac, driver

I'm trying to connect to a development board using a serial-USB adapter, and can't find the serial port on my Mac.

I tried `ls /dev/tty.*` and `ls /dev/cu.*`, and nothing relevant shows up on my Mac. I tried on a friends Mac and it **does** show up!

This must be because I had installed VCP / FTDI drivers in the past on my Mac (can't remember which, but there were a few), which must be interfering. I tried deleting the serial drivers `.kext` files in `/System/Library/Extensions/` and restarting, but that didn't work. I also tried reinstalling [these](https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm) drivers and restarting, but that didn't work. I've tried 3 other driver sources and that also didn't work.

Also, the device doesn't show up in `setting > Network`. Running Mac OS Mojave on both PCs.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can open System Report and check under USB to see if your USB device was found and initialized.

In terms of device files, you'll want to search for tty* and cu* - do not include the dot.

An easy way to spot the correct device is to run first:

```
find /dev > list1
```

then plug in the serial-USB adapter, and run:

```
find /dev > list2
```

and then finally:

```
diff list1 list
```

then the name of the new device for the serial-USB adapter should be shown.

Comment: I can see the device listed under USB devices in `System Report` with product ID, vendor ID and serial number. But I still don't see anything when I run just `tty*` or `cu*` or diff the lists.

Comment: You’ll need to tell us the actual IDs before we can help you more. Sounds like you haven’t got the appropriate driver installed.